# Update the capacity of golang buffered channel at runtime

Tags: go, channel

I am working on a piece of code wherein the capacity of the buffered channel should be a tunable parameter .i.e. after 1st time initialization of the buffered channel, I want to change the capacity of channel if required so.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 2)
    ch <- 1
    ch <- 2
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
    ch = make(chan int, 4)
    ch <- 3
    ch <- 4
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}
```

The above fails with error **fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!** after printing 1,3 and 4.

The following code works where all the value in the channel is read before updating its capacity.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 2)
    ch <- 1
    ch <- 2
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
    ch = make(chan int, 4)
    ch <- 3
    ch <- 4
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}
```

Could someone help here whether updating the buffered channel capacity is possible at runtime while it still holds some value that are yet to read.

Answer (score 1):

> Could someone help here whether updating the buffered channel capacity is possible at runtime while it still holds some value that are yet to read.

This is impossible. Once constructed via make a channel keeps it capacity which is unchangeable at runtime.

Comment: I was able to update the capacity of the channel after reading the values already available in the buffered channel.

Comment: @sks No, you where not. You just created a new channel with a larger capacity and did not change the old channel at all.